# Book recommendation for linear optimisation

Tags: optimization, reference-request, linear-programming, book-recommendation, simplex-method

I am currently in a linear optimisation class that uses a lot of the simplex algorithm and things relating to it. The book we are using is called *Linear Optimisation The Simplex Workbook* but it is beyond confusing and seems very poorly written to introduce someone to the area. I am looking for a book on linear optimisation that is better written and explains stuff well (i.e. talks about feasibility, dual-simplex, simplex, etc). I have asked my professor but he told me he likes this book and did not give me another recommendation, so I am stuck and frustrated trying to learn from the book and his notes (based off the book).

Comment: For linear programming, you might check out Vandenberghe's UCLA course EE 236a notes. http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/ee236a.html

Comment: What is your background? Which mathematics and/or computer science courses have you studied? Does the class you're in focus on using software, writing your own code, mathematical proofs, applications of linear optimisation, or other aspects?

Comment: I highly recommend Bertsekas' Introduction to Linear Optimization. It has a the full theory of linear programming and simplex method (+ other methods) and written in a very clear and comfortable manner

Answer (score 1):

Here are two excellent books

Linear and Nonlinear Programming 2nd Edition
by David G. Luenberger  (Author)

Convex Optimization – Boyd and Vandenberghe
[https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good recommendations given by Daniel S., may I suggest *Understanding and Using Linear Programming* by Matousek & Gärtner. It is a relatively small book (222 pages including an appendix on linear algebra, glossary and index), which might be an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Linear Programming 1: Introduction by Dantzig and Thapa. Dantzig created the simplex method, and the book serves as both an introduction to operations research and linear programming.

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387948331